# Reading config file with nested closures with Groovy's ConfigSlurper

Tags: groovy, closures, config, dsl

I would like to parse a data structure of closures (in this case a configuration file) with Groovy's [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html). The parsing result will be stored in an object hierarchy similar to the data structure. The only thing special about this data structure is the fact that some closure names repeat themselves within one closure e.g. `apple` and `green`. I looks like `ConfigSlurper` is using a `Map` internally that replaces already existing values. I was wondering if `ConfigSlurper` is actually able to handle these kinds of data structures. The Groovy version I use is 1.7.10. Alternatively, I tried to use `GroovyShell` to execute the closures but had some issues with the execution order.

```
String rules = """ 
fruits {
    apples {
        apple {
            id = 11

            colors {
                green {
                    name = 'test1'
                }

                green {
                    name = 'test2'
                }
            }            
        }

        apple {
            id = 12

            colors {
                green {
                    name = 'test3'
                }

                green {
                    name = 'test4'
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
"""

ConfigSlurper configSlurper = new ConfigSlurper()
def config = configSlurper.parse(rules)
println config
```

Comment: I'd probably start with ConfigSlurper, and override [the parse(Script,URL) method](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.groovy#L157), but after briefly looking at the code, it's not going to be a 2 minute job...  I'm guessing it's finding the old node in the scope variable, so using that which is not what you require...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse these rules using `GroovyShell`. Each closure of the rules needs to executed. The passed in `Binding` object lets you retrieve the values. For the repetitive closures I had to change the closure's `resolveStrategy` to `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the response a bit? May be a code snippet would explain it better.